# Create a modal dialog in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to open a modal dialog form in Ember - I have a form that I'd like users to submit a comment to before processing a workflow, but so far I've been unable to find any good documentation on how to open a modal dialog (where to put controllers, routes, models, etc.).  I am new to Ember, so please bear with me.  Thanks.

Comment: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/using_modal_dialogs/

Comment: More information -  I have a function already working properly. When the function is called, I want to have a modal dialog open so a user can enter a comment, then when the user selects 'ok' on the modal dialog, the modal form closes, and the entered comment is used in the function. I cannot seem to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

I followed [Ember Guru's guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20160111223404/http://ember.guru/2014/master-your-modals-in-ember-js) called "Master you're modals" on Ember, and they work great!

1. create template here:

create component called **my-modal**. Add the following in the components js:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    ok: function() {
      this.$('.modal').modal('hide');
      this.sendAction('ok');
        }
    },
    show: Ember.on('didInsertElement', function() {
        Ember.on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
          this.sendAction('close');
        }.bind(this), this.$('.modal').modal());
    })
});
```

2. Add the following code to the components hbs (template):

```html
<div class="modal fade"  data-backdrop="static">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2 class="modal-title text-center">{{title}}</h2>
      </div>
        {{yield}}
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

3. Now you need to create a template for the specific use of the modal where you call the component. Call it: waitingModal or loadingModal or whatever you like. In this modal template you call the component like so:

   {{#my-modal title='Loading Modal' ok='save' close='removeModal'}}

   {{/my-modal}}
4. Add the following to the application route:

   showModal: function(name, model) {
   this.render(name, {
   into: 'application',
   outlet: 'modal',
   model: model
   });
   },

Lastly to call a modal after clicking a button, in the button's action you need to call:

```
this.send('showModal','loading-modal');
```

where loading-modal is the specific template you're calling.

and to remove the modal:

```
this.send('removeModal');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks - saw that link to.  Again, I'm missing something, because I'm new to Ember and am having trouble following these examples.  For instance, none of these examples state where the various files are supposed to go.  What I really need is an example that states: 1. create template here; 2. create component here; 3. how to call modal;  4. how to bind value returned from modal; etc.

Comment: There is a demo linked to the post above with the whole code http://jsbin.com/qijaro/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I edited the answer, I hope it helps, otherwise comment with errors!

Comment: What if you aren't using Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

You could [use an addon](https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-modal-dialog) or [implement the recipe from the cookbook](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/using_modal_dialogs/).

Comment: Thanks - Unfortunately, I've seen both of those links before, but neither of them are very helpful.  What I need to learn and understand is where the various objects go and how they work together.  The cookbook link tells how to open and close modals, but does not give an example of how to actually do it - it states 'You can use a route's render method to render a specific controller and template into a named outlet.'.  What I need is an example of how to do that.

Comment: For the simplest solution use the addon. The Readme contains example code for a route's template and controller ("controller bound usage"). This is all you've got to do except for styling (you may use the included scss for that).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [ember-dialog](https://github.com/wheely/ember-dialog). Just one command `ember install ember-dialog` and dialogs on aboard. Here is example of use you're looking for:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  // Injecting dialog service
  dialog: Ember.inject.service(),

  model: { username: "Something" },

  actions: {
    showForm: function() {
      this.get("dialog").blank("path-to-some-form", this, {
        acceptHandler: "save"
      });
    },
    save: function(presenter) {
      var isValid = true;
      if (isValid) {
        // Closing presenter
        presenter.accept();
      }
    }
  }

});
```

Template (`/app/templates/path-to-some-form.hbs`):

```
<form {{action "accept" on='submit'}}>
  {{!-- contextObject here is controller --}}
  {{input value=contextObject.model.username}}
  <button class="w-btn w-btn__default" type="submit">Send</button>
  <button class="w-btn w-btn__danger" type="button" {{action "decline"}}>Cancel</button>
</form>
```